# Unable to reset wp-admin password by phpMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wp-admin

I have forgotten my wordpress website password. I am resetting password following https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password. I am able to change user_pass in phpMyadmin but when i enter username and password on wp-admin url, it gives `ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.`
and in phpMyadmin the user_pass is changed.

Comment: So did you disable your cookies? Can you confirm if they're being set or not?

Comment: it's enabled. i have checked.

Comment: Well WP says cookies are NOT enabled, so I'd say that's the most likely thing going wrong. Try it with another browser and see if it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Would you please add above things in `wp-config.php` file?